# No sound with Medion Akoya E2218T (MD 60200)

Tags: windows-8.1, sound-card

I can't find drivers for soundcard with Windows 8.1. How can I do to use soundcard ?

Answer (score 0):

#### I can't find drivers for soundcard with Windows 8.1

The drivers are located at:

https://www.medion.com/gb/service/_lightbox/treiber_details.php?did=16137&hgt=534

[image]

The download page doesn't indicate what version of Windows the drivers are for.

Comment: The sound driver from the link doesnt't work with the computer. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leonel Then you should [contact Medion](https://www.medion.com/mailing/service_gb.php)

Comment: The sound driver doesn't work

Comment: @Leonel See my previous comment - contact Medion.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to install Debian testing but

I had this error

[ 63.284610] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 63.284801] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 804 at /build/linux-lIgGMF/linux-4.8.11/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_uncore.c:802 __unclaimed_reg_debug+0x49/0x60 [i915]
[ 63.284806] Unclaimed write to register 0x1e0100
[ 63.284975] Modules linked in: ctr ccm fuse cmac bnep nls_ascii nls_cp437 vfat fat joydev rtsx_usb_ms rtsx_usb_sdmmc memstick hid_generic iTCO_wdt arc4 iTCO_vendor_support intel_rapl evdev coretemp kvm_intel kvm uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc iwlmvm irqbypass videobuf2_memops crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul videobuf2_v4l2 mac80211 videobuf2_core rtsx_usb btusb ghash_clmulni_intel videodev btrtl efi_pstore media btbcm usbhid btintel efivars pcspkr bluetooth i915 hid_multitouch iwlwifi cfg80211 snd_intel_sst_acpi rfkill drm_kms_helper snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_rt5645 snd_soc_rt5640 shpchp drm snd_soc_rl6231 lpc_ich mfd_core snd_soc_core snd_compress processor_thermal_device i2c_algo_bit intel_soc_dts_iosf snd_pcm kxcjk_1013 industrialio_triggered_buffer dw_dmac
[ 63.285099] kfifo_buf snd_timer video dw_dmac_core industrialio battery snd soundcore tpm_crb soc_button_array ac int3400_thermal tpm_tis int3403_thermal acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone tpm_tis_core tpm acpi_pad button efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb mbcache mmc_block i2c_hid hid crc32c_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper cryptd xhci_pci xhci_hcd usbcore usb_common thermal fjes sdhci_acpi i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core sdhci mmc_core
[ 63.285111] CPU: 2 PID: 804 Comm: kworker/u8:16 Not tainted 4.8.0-2-amd64 #1 Debian 4.8.11-1
[ 63.285114] Hardware name: MEDION E2218T MD60200/NT16H, BIOS 5.11 11/08/2016
[ 63.285135] Workqueue: events_unbound async_run_entry_fn
[ 63.285153] 0000000000000086 00000000e46da50a ffffffffbc1269f5 ffffa12a37d4bc98
[ 63.285166] 0000000000000000 ffffffffbbe7c16e 0000000000000000 ffffa12a37d4bcf0
[ 63.285179] 0000000000000000 00000000050007fc ffffa12a3a310738 ffffffffbc63739c
[ 63.285182] Call Trace:
[ 63.285201] [] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x77
[ 63.285215] [] ? __warn+0xbe/0xe0
[ 63.285226] [] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x5f/0x80
[ 63.285397] [] ? vlv_sideband_rw.constprop.0+0x187/0x210 [i915]
[ 63.285563] [] ? __unclaimed_reg_debug+0x49/0x60 [i915]
[ 63.285729] [] ? chv_write32+0x347/0x3a0 [i915]
[ 63.285880] [] ? intel_power_domains_init_hw+0x3ae/0x550 [i915]
[ 63.286021] [] ? i915_pm_thaw_early+0x10/0x10 [i915]
[ 63.286162] [] ? i915_drm_resume_early+0xb8/0x130 [i915]
[ 63.286175] [] ? dpm_run_callback+0x48/0x130
[ 63.286185] [] ? device_resume_early+0x7d/0x130
[ 63.286196] [] ? async_resume_early+0x19/0x40
[ 63.286204] [] ? async_run_entry_fn+0x34/0x140
[ 63.286214] [] ? process_one_work+0x160/0x410
[ 63.286223] [] ? worker_thread+0x4d/0x480
[ 63.286232] [] ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
[ 63.286242] [] ? kthread+0xcd/0xf0
[ 63.286254] [] ? ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[ 63.286264] [] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x190/0x190
[ 63.286271] ---[ end trace ee9b4eba38a434bb ]---